# How to use Kafka Streams' Processor API with ksqlDB?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I am trying to find the better way to store our data.

ksqlDB provides terminal, UI view to query streams and tables, which makes much easier to handle data. Whilst PAPI's persistence state store in saved all in memory and only way to view is through Interactive Queries, which should be pre-set and exposed via REST (no terminal, no UI so cannot play with the data easily).

Can we merge Kafka streams Processor API and KsqlDB when saving the state OR they are completing different ways of handling the streams of events?

Comment: A pseudo-code deems necessary as I hardly understand the question. Which one is in control - a Kafka Streams application or ksqlDB?